# UICollectionView ReusableView for header

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

In the project I have used a chart in the header of `UICollectionViewController` and when user taps on each `cell` the chart data is updated.
Now I do not want the reuse header to be updated because of each time a `scrolling` chart ui is used.

in code

```
collectionHeaderView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: What exactly is the question / problem ?

Comment: prevent the reuse in method : - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you would like to do is merely prevent reusing, then initialize the header view only ONCE ( for example in viewDidLoad), then return it immediately in following method

```
collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

It's a dead simple answer, but I hope this helps.